# Coredump analysis for shared libraries in exe

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, coredump

I'm trying to back trace a coredump for a exe which use shared libraries. But it is not returning the function names as the issues is in. So files.

Kindly suggest some ways how to bt the coredump for. So files. Did i need to change my build procedure!? Is it is possible to bt the core for exe with.so?

Comment: You need to provide much more details for a useful answer, starting with: what do you actually see? Is the machine where the `core` was generated the same as one where it is analyzed? Etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.